# Local MathJax loading with turbolinks in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reload, mathjax, turbolinks

I need to use local instance of MathJax with Rails4 application, but there is problem with turbolinks reloading.

I use [mathjax-rails](https://github.com/pmq20/mathjax-rails) gem (with updated mathjax) for excluding MJ distributive from project directory.

It's require to add gem's route

```
#routes.rb
mathjax 'mathjax'
```

and helper in layout

```
<%= mathjax_tag %>
```

but when page loads with turbolinks - mathjax doesn't run.

If I call mathjax reload function on page ready()

```
MathJax.Hub.Typeset();
```

it will loads in fallback mode - with images instead of fonts.

Then i found [another solution](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/mathjax.html), which reloads MathJax with jQuery Ajax.
It works perfect with CDN

```
http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

but when I changed path to local distributive of MathJax

```
/mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
```

main mathjax script can't include other js files, because lost dist root path (/mathjax)

And when I set root path manualy with config

```
root: "/mathjax"
```

it's loading without errors, but does nothing.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution for Rails4

```
$(document).on 'page:load', ->
  window.MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```